# Best way to refactor methods that have the same code but different return values

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I have this piece of code:

```
public A methodA(X answer) {
  ... 
  return A;
}

public B methodB(X answer) {
  ... 
  return B;
}
```

So, for example, I have two call those methods in different methods, because the return type is different, so for example, on the controller:

```
public A version1(X answer) {
 ...
 A ant = methodA();
 ...
}

public Bversion2(X answer) {
 ...
 B bee = methodB();
 ...
}
```

The point is that every other single line of code is the same, except the calls specified. How can I refactor this code in Java to avoid using duplicated code?

Comment: Could you share a more complete example? How is the duplicated code related to the return value?

Comment: What I was thinking is: every other line of code, is the same on the methods, so the problem is the return type.

Comment: There's not enough context here to think about this. Could be a generic, could be a utility function, could be anything.

Comment: Unless generics are used, I don’t see how it’s possible for identical code to produce results of different types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd extract the unique part of the code to a [`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), move the common code to one method, and have the original methods call that underlying method with a supplier:

```java
public A version1(X answer) {
    return unversioned (answer, this::methodA);
}

public B version2(X answer) {
    return unversioned (answer, this::methodB);
}

private <T> T unversioned(X answer, Supplier<T> supplier) {
    // Some code before the supplier
    T result = supplier.get();
    // Some code after the supplier, that may interact with the result
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Understood! But, for example. when calling ```this:methodA``` it will throw an error, won't it?

Comment: @CarryFlag I don't understand this statement. Why would it throw an exception?

Comment: Because the method reference (methodA) is different from Supplier

Comment: @CarryFlag `Supplier` is a functional interface. Any method that takes no arguments and returns a `T` is by definition a `Supplier<T>`. `methodA` in your example is a `Supplier<A>`, and this code should compile just fine.